# Rstudio - How to show plot output in bottom right pane?

Tags: rstudio

I used a qplot, but instead of the plot showing in the plots tab on the bottom right, it decides to show in the top left. How do I move all the outputs to the bottom right pane?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have version 1.0.44 of RStudio on a mac - you are using RMarkdown, which, by default in recent versions, causes output to be shown inline within the markdown page.

To undo this behavior, open RStudio->Preferences, and select the R Markdown group on the left. Uncheck the box that says "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents".

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

The answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40570719/6169225) is correct for ***Mac*** - in the Windows version of R Studio, select 'Tools' --> 'Global Options...' and you will be brought to the window that you see in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying options in R-Notebook or R Markdown, you can create a new **R script** and paste your desired code there. After running the code, the output will be displayed in the Plots window located at the bottom-right corner, where you can access various Export options:

[image: R figure from R script outputted to Plots window, ready for export]

It would indeed be convenient to edit the inline R Markdown output graphs with the click of a button ([feature request?](https://community.rstudio.com/)). But with this copy-to-R-script workaround, you can easily save the code that generates your figure with the figure, which might be useful for later reference.